# Calculate average for incremental values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, average

I have been trying to create a SQL query to calculate a daily average of a incremental value in SQL.

This is how the table looks like

```
Name   Date              Value
-------------------------------------
Item1  2014/04/22 10:00    900
Item2  2014/04/22 10:00    200
.....
ItemN  2014/04/22 10:00    480

Item1  2014/04/23 10:00    1000
Item2  2014/04/23 10:00    324
.....
ItemN  2014/04/23 10:00    780

Item1  2014/04/23 10:10    1050
Item2  2014/04/23 10:10    424
.....
ItemN  2014/04/23 10:10    880
```

As result for the query I would like to produce something like this:

```
Name     Daily_Average
-----------------------    
Item1    150
Item2    224
...
ItemN    400
```

For this particular example I have calculated the Daily Average by taking the maximum & minimum value for the item, substract the minimum from the maximum and divided it by the number of days (only a single day has passed on the example).

It's has been a long time since I don't play around with SQL so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Subtracting minimum from maximum is not really an average - doesn't it sound weird to you that your "average" for item 1 is 150 and is of values 900, 1000 and 1050?

Comment: Tomas, I think it is 150 assuming that this is the maximun value for this item, a since only one day has passed ...

Comment: Is there an entry for every day or can there be gaps? If there can be gaps: How shall they be treated?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, you seem to want something like:

```
select i.item,
       (max(i.value) - min(i.value)) / count(distinct cast(i.date as date)) as Daily_Average
from items i
group by i.item;
```

It is unclear what "divided it by the number of days" really means.  I understood this in the colloquial sense.  However, you seem to be storing time values on a column labelled as "date".  So, it is unclear which you want to count (with or without the time value).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I have changed your query to this one: select i.item,
       (max(i.value) - min(i.value)) / DATEDIFF(day,(SELECT MIN(i.date) FROM i),
    (SELECT MAX(i.date) FROM i)) as Daily_Average
from items i
group by i.item; and I think that it was exaclty what I was looking for.

Comment: @user3568524 . . . That is yet another interpretation of "number of days".  Language is a curious thing.

Comment: Hi Gordon. The thing here is that I don't mind taking into average value the gaps, like weekend and holidays where these values are not incremented. I should have said the difference in days from the first date that we have values to the last.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the average based on the number of days, you approach it in two ways: number records with of unique dates (you don't count gaps in this case) or number of days between first and last date (counting gap days too). Gordon Linoff provided the solution in the first case.

Here is the solution in the second case:

```
select Name,
   (max(value) - min(Value)) / datediff(day, min(cast([date] as date)), max(cast([date] as date))) as Daily_Average
from table1
group by Name
```

Note: this will not work if there's only one date. When you have 2 consecutive dates you treat the number of days as 1 based on your question, so I'm not sure what should happen if there's only one day.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below for calculating the average using your rules:

```
 SELECT Name,
        CASE
             WHEN DaysDifference > 0 THEN ValueDifference / DaysDifference
             ELSE ValueDifference / 1 -- Handles DateDifference = 0 
        END AS AverageValue
   FROM
        (
         SELECT Name,
                MAX(Value) - MIN(Value) AS ValueDifference,
                DATEDIFF(day, MIN(Date), MAX(DATE)) AS DaysDifference
           FROM Incrementals
          GROUP BY Name
        ) AS Summary
```

(Full SQL Fiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43033/1/0))

I've assumed you just want the average value when there are no days difference, but you could change this as appropriate.

Comment: Ni ninjapig, thanks for poinint me out that there could be no day difference. I think that your solution deals really goodwith that. Thanks